# Re-installing GnuPG Suit - should I keep a copy of keyring?

Tags: gnupg

I am currently going through PGP & GPG book.  I installed GnuPG Suit a while back but did not verify checksum nor signature.  I somehow created a key.  Obviously by playing around.  I now want to verify that the software is authentic but don't have the dmg file.  Should I delete the software and re-download?  And if so, do I copy from it my keyring?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to export keys from your keyring and save them to a secure place.

As written here, https://gist.github.com/chrisroos/1205934 :

`gpg --export-ownertrust > path/to/secure/directory/gpg.txt`

And, to import it back, you could :

`gpg --import-ownertrust your/ownertrust/gpg.txt`

Comment: Right.  Great.  And I should re-install because I don't have the .dmg file which prevents me from ensuring the download is authentic, is this right?  There is no other way for me to check the checksum?

Comment: If you already install gnupg suite on your computer and through it could have been corrupted or infected, you cannot trust your machine anymore

Comment: The best thing to do would be to redownload the GPGsuite after a complete format. But if you're not *that* paranoid, you could just reinstall it safely by checking the signature of the DMG file. You can also use this GNUpg https://www.gnupg.org/download/integrity_check.html help page for more information

Comment: Redownload "after a complete format" - alright, how is this different from reinstalling by checking the signature of DMG file?  I don't have the DMG file.  Thanks loads.  I'm getting good sense from your answers already, just must verify.

Comment: What if the copy you downloaded previously had been infected by a virus on your computer ?when you'll reinstall gnupg, the malicious software can hook back on it. And the new pair of keys you'll generate could be sent to an hacker. But this is again, highly paranoid

Comment: Great.  I want to cover all doors for experience.  How technically is the redownload "after a complete format" different from the less-paranoid option?  I now understand the difference in theory - thanks! - and want to understand the technical difference between the two options.

Comment: Even if you download the same file, if you are not sure about the OS integrity, you can't be sure it won't be corrupt. A system format should wipe out most of viruses, and should leave you with a clean system

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions and following through with my thinking.  Goodbye.